# Floating point exception during mining (monerod)

Tags: monerod, mining, cpu-mining

I have a strange error during mining. I'm running solo miner on AMD K10 (Phenom 9650). It is not for profit, more or less, it is for experiments. Anyway, I was able to sync the everything and mining on CPU started successfully. After few hours, (I'm not sure how many exactly) let's say 20h, the daemon stopped with error "Float point exception". I thought it is a random error and started it again. After few hours I got the same error and so on and so on. Monerod (command line tools) is running on linux x86 (Lubuntu) and I'm mining on 1 thread. What exactly this error means and can it be fixed?

Comment: This looks like a bug which should be addressed in the GitHub bug tracker rather than here. There’s hardly any place in the code that uses floating point, so this error seems very unusual. It’d be highly appreciated if you could provide a detailed stack trace by building the daemon in debug mode and running it with gdb.

Comment: Later today I'll post the issue on GitHub and I'll try to build it in debug mode. It will be slow debug, it crashes once in few hours :)

Comment: Thank you for contributing! It's crucial to make the daemon absolutely stable and bug-free:)

Comment: To get crash info, you need to run `ulimit -c unlimited` and possibly `echo core | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` before running monerod. Then, after it crashes: `gdb /path/to/monerod core.*`, then, when gdb has started: `bt`. Replace /path/to/monerod with the actual path.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay, but I had work and didn't have time to debug it. As info I would like to mention that actually it crashes when trying to synchronize a new block and mining at the same time.